# AddEventListener functions not working after changing express js server-side file

Tags: javascript, html, express

i had had an index.js file, where i kept my express js code, and my homepage.js file thats connected to the html file thats being displayed through index.js suddenly stopped working after making some changes in the index js file. by "suddenly stopped working" i mean that some of the addeventlistener callback functions for the buttons stopped being called. heres the homepage.js code:

```
new_group_button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    new_group_pop_up_section.style.display = "flex";
    document.querySelector("#group-name-input").focus();
});
document.querySelector("#new-group-exit-button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    new_group_pop_up_section.style.display = "none";
});
document.querySelector("#new-swap-exit-button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    new_swap_pop_up_section.style.display = "none";
});
document.querySelector("#new-swap-button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    new_swap_pop_up_section.style.display = "flex";
    document.querySelector("#new-swap-title").focus();
});
sign_in_button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    window.location.href = "login.html";
});
add_button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (add_button.textContent === "add"){
        add_button.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        add_button.textContent = "remove";
        add_button.style.color = "black";
        friends_added.friends_added_total++;
        friends_added.friends_added.push(add_button.closest(".friend-profile-new-group-inner-pop-up-section").querySelector(".friend-name").textContent);
    }
    else {
        add_button.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        add_button.textContent = "add";
        add_button.style.color = "lightgreen";
        friends_added.friends_added_total--;
        friends_added.friends_added.splice(add_button.closest(".friend-profile-new-group-inner-pop-up-section").querySelector(".friend-name").textContent, 1);
    }
    document.querySelector("#total-friends-in-this-group").textContent = `${friends_added.friends_added_total}`;
});
document.querySelector("#create-group-button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    let all_radio_buttons = document.querySelector("#group-types").querySelectorAll(".group-type-button")
    let selected_radio_button;
    let should_return = true
    let group_title = document.querySelector("#group-name-input");
    let group_description = document.querySelector("#group-description");

    if ( group_title.value === "" )
        return;
    if ( group_description.value === "" )
        return;
    for (const radio_button of all_radio_buttons){
        if ( radio_button.checked === true ){
            selected_radio_button = radio_button;
            should_return = false;
            continue
        }
    }
    if ( should_return === true )
        return;
    let new_group_code = 
    `
    <button class = "group">
        <img class = "group-image" src = "https://buffer.com/cdn-cgi/image/w=1000,fit=contain,q=90,f=auto/library/content/images/size/w1200/2023/10/free-images.jpg">
        <article class = group-article>
            <h2 class = group-title>${group_title.value}</h2>
            <h3 class = group-notification><span>account</span>: <span>xbox-360</span><span class = "group-time-since-notified"> 15m</span></h3>
        </article>
    </button>
    `;
    groups_list.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", new_group_code);
    new_group_pop_up_section.style.display = "none";
    group_title.value = "";
    group_description.value = "";
    all_radio_buttons[0].checked = false;
    all_radio_buttons[1].checked = false;
});
groups_switch_button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if ( is_in_group_mode === true )
        return;

    is_in_group_mode = true;
    new_group_button.style.display = "inline-block"

    friends_list.style.display = "none";
    groups_list.style.display = "flex";

    groups_switch_button.classList.remove("not-greyed-out");
    groups_switch_button.classList.add("greyed-out");
    
    friends_switch_button.classList.remove("greyed-out");
    friends_switch_button.classList.add("not-greyed-out");

    groups_friends_search_bar.placeholder = "search groups";
    search_groups = true;

})
friends_switch_button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if ( is_in_group_mode === false )
        return;

    is_in_group_mode = false;
    new_group_button.style.display = "none"

    friends_list.style.display = "flex";
    groups_list.style.display = "none"

    groups_switch_button.classList.remove("greyed-out");
    groups_switch_button.classList.add("not-greyed-out");

    friends_switch_button.classList.remove("not-greyed-out");
    friends_switch_button.classList.add("greyed-out");

    groups_friends_search_bar.placeholder = "search friends";
    search_groups = false;
});
account_friends_switch_button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    account_friends_switch_button.classList.remove("not-greyed-out");
    account_friends_switch_button.classList.add("greyed-out");

    account_groups_switch_button.classList.remove("greyed-out");
    account_groups_switch_button.classList.add("not-greyed-out");

    swaps_switch_button.classList.remove("greyed-out");
    swaps_switch_button.classList.add("not-greyed-out");

    account_search_bar.placeholder = "search friends";
});
account_groups_switch_button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    account_groups_switch_button.classList.remove("not-greyed-out");
    account_groups_switch_button.classList.add("greyed-out");

    account_friends_switch_button.classList.remove("greyed-out");
    account_friends_switch_button.classList.add("not-greyed-out");

    swaps_switch_button.classList.remove("greyed-out");
    swaps_switch_button.classList.add("not-greyed-out");

    account_search_bar.placeholder = "search groups";
});
swaps_switch_button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    swaps_switch_button.classList.remove("not-greyed-out");
    swaps_switch_button.classList.add("greyed-out");

    account_groups_switch_button.classList.remove("greyed-out");
    account_groups_switch_button.classList.add("not-greyed-out");

    account_friends_switch_button.classList.remove("greyed-out");
    account_friends_switch_button.classList.add("not-greyed-out");

    account_search_bar.placeholder = "search swaps";
});
collapsable_section_exit_button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    collapsable_section_exit_button.style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector("#collapsable-section").style.display = "none";
    swap_information_section.style.display = "flex";
});
create_swap_button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    let new_swap = 
    `
    <button class = "button-for-swap-page">
        <img src = "https://buffer.com/cdn-cgi/image/w=1000,fit=contain,q=90,f=auto/library/content/images/size/w1200/2023/10/free-images.jpg" class = "swap-image">
        <article class = "article">
            <h2 class = "swap-title">${new_swap_title.value}</h2>
            <p class = "swap-information">${swap_description.value}</p>
            <div class = "extra-swap-details">
                <h3>reputable swapper<br>near you</h3>
                <h4><span>${select_condition.value}</span> | <span>${amount_available_query.value} available</span><br>by <a>account</a> | <span>yesterday</span></h4>
            </div>
        </article>
    </button>
    `;
    new_swap_pop_up_section.style.display = "none";
    new_swap_title.value = "";
    swap_description.value = "";
    amount_available_query.value.value = "";
    select_condition.value = "used";
    swaps_section.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", new_swap);
});
button_for_swap_page.addEventListener("click", function(){
    history.saver(history.elements[history.elements.length - 1].element).style.display = "none";
    history.elements.push({
        element: history.saver(individual_swap_section),
        display_type: "flex"
    });
    individual_swap_section.style.display = "flex";
});
account_button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    history.saver(history.elements[history.elements.length - 1].element).style.display = "none";
    history.elements.push({
        element: history.saver(account_page_section),
        display_type: "flex"
    });
    account_page_section.style.display = "flex";
});
group.addEventListener("click", function(){
    history.saver(history.elements[history.elements.length - 1].element).style.display = "none";
    history.elements.push({
        element: history.saver(group_page_section),
        display_type: "flex"
    });
    group_page_section.style.display = "flex";
});
group_image_button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    history.saver(history.elements[history.elements.length - 1].element).style.display = "none";
    history.elements.push({
        element: history.saver(extra_group_information_section),
        display_type: "flex"
    });
    extra_group_information_section.style.display = "flex";
});
```

i removed some code from the homepage.js file, but nothing fixed it, this seemed to happen immediatley after changing the index.js file
by the way, i couldnt include my code in a code block, because stack overflow would call it spam